# How to create flutter list linear gradien widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnKZt.png]
How can I make a widget like in the image
and how to control the degree

The shape 2

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Rtq.png]

Comment: This is too broad. Please make a more specific question and add your researches.

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation?

Comment: yup .. Andrey Portnoy

Comment: What have you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate UI as you required

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 100.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10.0)),
      gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.yellow[700], Colors.redAccent],
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: Alignment.centerRight, tileMode: TileMode.clamp)),
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: new Icon(Icons.cloud, color: Colors.white70,),
        ),
          new Expanded(child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text('New York', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              new SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
              new Text('Sunny', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white70),),
            ],)),
        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Text('12°', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white70),),)

      ],),
    );
  }
```

[image: demo_ui]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for linear gradient then you can use **[LinearGradient](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html)** in **[Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)**.

```
      new Container(
        child: new Text('Hello'),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          gradient: new LinearGradient( // <-- This is what you need to do
            colors: [
              Colors.red[200],
              Colors.red
            ],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
            new Radius.circular(10.0)
          )
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      )
```

If you wish to have custom design boxes Container is what you'll need.

**NOTE**: Always check the docs first. https://docs.flutter.io